# Where can I find the snarkverify precompile (opcode) implementation in parity and the example coin mixing contract that utilizes it?

Tags: contract-development, parity, privacy, zero-knowledge

With the recent announcement of zkSNARKs support and the ZoE (ZeroCash over Ethereum) mixing contract (https://z.cash/blog/zksnarks-in-ethereum.html)

Where can I find the mentioned parity branch and any accompanying examples of the coin mixing contract?

Answer (score 2):

The commit that implements snarkverify in Parity: https://github.com/gancherj/parity/commit/b820abf755e216ccf24640549735412ec02dac62

The example coin mixing contract: https://github.com/zcash/babyzoe/blob/master/zoe/contract/mixer.sol